# Make Ekiga always ring on the speakers

Tags: audio, ekiga

I'm running Fedora 20. I'd like to make Ekiga always ring using my speakers instead of my headset.

The list of devices for ringing are:

- HDA Intel
- Alsa output
- PulseAudio
- Default

I have no idea of how this maps into real world hardware. How to always make it ring on the speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Ekiga manual](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Manual) this dialog looks like where you'd set the option of where you want the ringing to be routed to the corresponding audio output.

[image: ss#1]

**NOTE:** These screens were apparently removed in 4.2+ of Ekiga. I've only got access to 4.0.1 which still has them. I'm on both F19 and F20 which appear to have this older version, so this solution should work in either of those instances.

I believe you can select "Default", and then select the desired output device from the list.